# Why do my image links not work on iphones and ipads?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ipad

Aware that you can't have link rollovers / hovering on ipads and iphones I have tried changing my rollover backgrounds to clickable images for iphones and ipads however the links still don't work on them. Can anyone see why these won't work. Here is the css used to target ipads:

```css
 /* iPad [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

 div.website_bck a img
 {
  display: block!important;
  width: 100%!important;
     }
  div#hi_hats, div#marbella, div#bcl, div#chinahouse, div#suponix, div#pa, div#upwardMb, div#salon, div#fasbet, div#wrayEnt, div#box, div#bcl_logo, div#greenSeeds, div#lilyRose, div#stationery_suponix, div#stationery_bcl, div#stationery_charmel, div#stationery_box, div#adverts_digital_betfred, div#adverts_digital_itvBets, div#adverts_digital_bingo, div#adverts_digital_casino, div#adverts_digital_freeBet, div#adverts_print_betfred1, div#adverts_print_betfred2, div#adverts_print_bingo, div#adverts_print_hi_hats, div#adverts_print_fasbet, div#other_betfred_presspack, div#other_betfred_survey, div#other_fasbet_stand, div#other_betfred_scratchcards, div#other_betfred_paysafe, div#other_hi_hats_cd, div#other_fasbet_demo, div#other_betfred_bingo_game
 {
  background-image: none;
 }
  }
```

Here is the css code used to target iphones which is the same as above but uses a different media query:

```css
/* iPhone [portrait + landscape] */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 div.website_bck a img
 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%!important;
     }
      div#hi_hats, div#marbella, div#bcl, div#chinahouse, div#suponix, div#pa, div#upwardMb, div#salon, div#fasbet, div#wrayEnt, div#box, div#bcl_logo, div#greenSeeds, div#lilyRose, div#stationery_suponix, div#stationery_bcl, div#stationery_charmel, div#stationery_box, div#adverts_digital_betfred, div#adverts_digital_itvBets, div#adverts_digital_bingo, div#adverts_digital_casino, div#adverts_digital_freeBet, div#adverts_print_betfred1, div#adverts_print_betfred2, div#adverts_print_bingo, div#adverts_print_hi_hats, div#adverts_print_fasbet, div#other_betfred_presspack, div#other_betfred_survey, div#other_fasbet_stand, div#other_betfred_scratchcards, div#other_betfred_paysafe, div#other_hi_hats_cd, div#other_fasbet_demo, div#other_betfred_bingo_game
 {
  background-image: none;
 } 

}
```

The website page is http://www.i4dsign.co.uk/portfolio.html#portfolio_nav . Here is an example of the html used for each link:

```html
<div class="website_bck left" id="hi_hats">
  <a href="portfolio_hi_hats.html">
    <img src="images/website_hiHats.jpg" alt="The Hi-Hats: Wedding and Function Band">
  </a>
  <div class="rollover">

    <div class="mask">
      <h2>The Hi-Hats</h2>
      <h3>Wedding & Function Band</h3>
      <a href="portfolio_hi_hats.html">More Information</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: image is already a block element. as a suggestion Set display:block for <a>

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help but thanks for trying. Actually the image wasn't already a block element as it was set to display:none so it only is present for iphones and ipads.